# JQuery Ajax success is not getting executed

Tags: jquery

`Ajax` call is made successfully. And I see a `JSON` response. But some how the method `fieldValidated` is not getting called when the message return is a `success`.

Using `Spring` in the back

`JSON` response `'{ "valid" : "false", "message" : "Some message" }'`

```
   function thisMethodIsCalledOnCursorOutFromInputField() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '${pageContext. request. contextPath}/X.htm',
        data: {
            someId: $('#someId').val()
        },
        contentType: "*/*",
        dataType: "json", //Have also tried with "text"
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('response=', data);
            fieldValidated("someId", data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('response=', data);
            fieldValidated("emailId",data);
        }
    });
    }
```

Console.log

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o jquery-1.10.1.js:550
x.extend.parseJSON jquery-1.10.1.js:550 
$.ajax.error X.htm:115
c jquery-1.10.1.js:3074
p.fireWith jquery-1.10.1.js:3186 
k jquery-1.10.1.js:8255
r
```

Comment: is it on the same domain?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: hmm, you trying to get an html, did your try that as type?

Comment: Are you sure `fieldValidated` is **not** being called? Or does it not execute properly? Maybe the error is in that function?

Comment: Yes its on same domain; I have updated the console log; HTTP status is `200` with the `JSON` string; Have not tried HTML type; `fieldValidated` is not getting called for `error` or `success`

Comment: Are you getting some output to the console from `console.log('response=', data);` ?

Comment: Getting nothing in the console.log. I just see the error message pasted above under `Console.log`. Though the HTTP response is success. Exception under `firebug` - SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: The error message kind of suggests that what your server is returning **isn't** valid JSON. Are those single quotes part of the text received from the server in response to the AJAX request? If so, remove them and try it again.

Comment: That was it. I guess. Had to remove the extra single quote. Makes me look so stu`. @Anthony can you post your answer so that I can up vote it.

Comment: your server does not return json content type. read this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type

Comment: @BobSort Thanks for providing the link. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that the response from the server isn't valid JSON. If the response is literally

```
'{ "valid" : "false", "message" : "Some message" }'
```

then you'll need to remove the single quotes, since they're not necessary to indicate to JavaScript that it's a string and aren't valid JSON (strings are contained within double quotes).

Comment: Actually he need to set content-type to `Application/JSON` too.

Comment: @BobSort He hasn't posted any server-side code, so I can't tell if he needs to or not (though jQuery's going to treat the text response as JSON regardless). If you're talking about the `contentType` property on the AJAX request, that refers to the data being sent, not received, and it doesn't look like he's sending JSON to me.

Answer (score 1):

The error you see in console suggest that, jquery is expecting a mime type JSON.

You will need to set your content type to `application/json`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type) post explains it.

On the other hand your JSON output need to be valid too,

you can check validity of your JSON output using [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com/). you can download and run it from your local http server too

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON call return an array like yours, you have to specifically call for what you need.

fieldValidated("someId", data.message);

That might be your problem.

Comment: There should not be a problem passing an array to a function.

Comment: It's not an array, anyway, it's an object. Both should be fine to pass to a function though.

Comment: I handle the JSON in the method call `fieldValidated` as you say but its not even getting called.